# Display Current Time

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I want to display the current time on the screen.

I have the piece of code to display the time (one time)
I have the pice of code to refresh (Timer

I can't make the two work together to keep the time updated on the screen.

PS: I know that print("FIRE") will not display the time but every combination of the 2 I tried leads to an error.

```
func getCurrentDateTime() {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .long
    let str = formatter.string (from: Date ())
    TimeNow.text = str
}

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func fire()
{
   print("FIRE")
}
```

My objective is to display a big clock on the screen.

Comment: `self.getCurrentDateTime()` in `fire`. should update the time. However, you should update with a shorter interval, e.g. `0.1`. Please, show us what combination leads to an error and what error.

Comment: @Sulthan 1 second would be enough. OP would just need to schedule the timer to fireAt the next even second

Comment: if `TimeNow` is a label or other UI element, you have to call `getCurentDateTime()` on the main thread. In other words, use `DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in self?.getCurrentDateTime() }`  in your `fire` func.

Also remember that the timer will retain `self`, which will cause a retain cycle unless you invalidate the timer before you try to deallocate whatever `self` is. That's an easy memory leak to make.

Comment: I can't edit my text above anymore, but the `[weak self] in` is unnecessary because you can't get a retain cycle in that code. Force of habit.

The code should be:
`DispatchQueue.main.async { self.getCurrentDateTime() }`

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is the block based API of `Timer` – this avoids the `@objc` attribute – and to create the `DateFormatter` once.

And please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.

```
var timer : Timer!

...

let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .long
    return formatter
}()

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in 
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.timeNow.text = formatter.string(from: Date())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian!

I have an error on the line starting with the `timer =` It says Expected Declaration. I tried putting `var timer : Timer!` at different places but nothing make this error go away. Thanks!

Comment: Please put `var timer = ...` in front or timer, or more formally `var timer : Timer = ...` and in place of ellipsis the rest of the expression of vadian.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and it works, if you have connected your TimeNow as an IBOutlet UIlabel to your storyboard view.
I have set the timer in my viewDidLoad.

You may try either the code below or the main thread flavor. In fact it is recommended to update UI from nain thread. In my case both worked:

```
@objc func fire()
{
    print("FIRE")
    getCurrentDateTime()

}

@objc func fire()
{
   print("FIRE")
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.getCurrentDateTime()
   }

}
```

Comment: `[weak self]` is nonsense in GCD closures because they definitely don't cause retain cycles.

Comment: The approach without the dispatch is not safe if `getCurrentDateTime` makes UIKit calls. It may work, and it may not. Sooner or later it will crash. UIKit is not threadsafe, so you must call it from the main thread.

If the clock is being displayed using something like `SpriteKit`, then the first approach is fine, no need to dispatch to the main thread.

Comment: Thank you @Konstantinos & vadian. I tried both and in each case it opens the class on this line:

AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

and to the left I have this error

Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: @Matt In my test there was no issue. Could you clean up your project,  build again and retry?